# How to transfert data messages from AWS IoT Core to Document DB

Tags: aws-iot, aws-documentdb, aws-iot-core

I'm want to save device messages from AWS IoT Core to a DocumentDB database. But there is no Rule possible like there is for connect DynamoDB to Io Core. How can I do that ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, AWS IoT Rules engine doesn't integrate with DocumentDB. The simplest way to achieve this, in my opinion, is to trigger an AWS Lambda function that will write the item into DocumentDB. Depending on the volume of messages to be written, you might consider adding Kinesis (or SQS) between the IoT Rule and your lambda to write items in batch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thinks it's the only way to do that.